# How to enable printer pooling for a printer

Tags: c#, printing, wmi, pooling

I am trying to activate "print pooling" on many printservers for many printers, and assign a second Port to that printer.
I was not able to find a way to do this programatically. Seems, that neither WMI, nor .NET Printserver / Printer Class can deliver this setting.
Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is: rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry

Documentation for this does not mention printer pooling, but pooling is done simply by specifying more than one Portname.

I first saw this here https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-enable-printer-pooling-via-command-prompt.905916/

Microsoft has TechNet documentation you can search for, but here is more readable documentation: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php

I haven't tried it myself yet, because I have a different problem, and I stumbled across that in my searches for deeper technical details on printer pooling.